# FlUrl 4.0: how to work with WithOAuthBearerToken and dependency container

Tags: flurl

In FlUrl version 3.X, I have been working with my REST Api in this way:

- I have the singleton instance `_noAuthClient`. With this client, I make a Login call to Rest Api, which returns JWT token.
- Then I am creating another singleton instance `_authClient` with the call below and all subsequent calls are done through this `_authClient`. This ensures compatibility with AspNet.Core authorization.

```
    private IFlurlClient CreateAuthClient()
    {
        lock (_authLock)
        {
            if (AuthToken == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("AuthenticateAsync was not called. Client can be accessed after AuthenticateAsync() call.");
            }

            return _noAuthClient.WithOAuthBearerToken(AuthToken.AuthToken);
        }
    }
```

I think that in 4.0 this approach with singleton clients is already deprecated and I would like to use a more current approach. Could you give me some direction?
I am implementing 4.0 Flurl with Dependency container. Registering `IFlurlClientCache` as a singleton, configuring by `.WithDefaults(builder => ...)`.

I have found [this interesting solution](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/678#issuecomment-1070934179), but this is also not aligned with 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

For using DI and needing precise control of your client instances, I recommend using [named clients](https://flurl.dev/docs/clients/#using-dependency-injection), an idea that was...uh...borrowed from .NET's `IHttpClientFactory`. Although you can pre-configure your clients during DI registration, I think you'll find that `GetOrAdd` is the way to go here, since you won't have that auth token at startup (I'm assuming).

One thing to look out for is that in your code sample, `_noAuthClient.WithOAuthBearerToken` doesn't return a new client - *it modifies the original*. To have 2 instances, they each need to be created/configured from scratch.

But that doesn't mean you can't use a shared method for both. I'd suggest something like this in your service class:

```cs
private IFlurlClient GetOrCreateClient(bool auth)
{
    if (auth && AuthToken == null)
        throw ...

    var name = "some-service-" + (auth ? "auth" : "anon");

    return _clientCache.GetOrAdd(name, "https://some-service.com", builder => {
        // configure builder for either client
        
        if (auth)
            builder.WithOAuthBearerToken(AuthToken.AuthToken);
    });
}
```

Here `_clientCache` is your injected `IFlurlClientCache` singleton. `GetOrAdd` is thread-safe and ensures that the builder action happens lazily and at most once per client name; no need for locks here. All other methods in your class can simply call `GetOrCreateClient(...).Request(...)` as needed to invoke Flurl calls, and no matter how often that happens, the `GetOrAdd` behavior ensures that no more than 2 clients are created/configured for the life of your application.

Comment: Thanks for excellent sample, I will go this way.